# python name mangling and global variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#global variable
_test__x=13

class test:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.__x=x
    def rex(self):
        return __x

d = test(5)
print(d.rex())
```

if I run this code it will return 13
I know that the interpreter applied name mangling so the variable `__x` became `_test__x`
but this is the same as the global variable.

i tried to use `self._test__x` but it did not work

How to access the `__x` variable declared in `__init __.py` but not the global variable?

Comment: `self.__x = ...` and `return self.__x`...  right now it's just a local variable. No mangling involved.

Comment: I think is not something you could do (at least not easily), and _is not a bug but a feature_ (it is actually part of the specification, apparently). See: https://bugs.python.org/issue27793

Comment: @bitomic. I'm not seeing the feature part from that thread. It's documented, but admittedly not behaving sensibly

Comment: Ok , I tried to but self.__x in __init __ and return self.__x in rex() and it works properly

Comment: I'll write up an answer. This is one of the ugliest things in python, IMO

Comment: @MadPhysicist: This actually used to be [explicitly advertised in the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5/tut/node67.html#SECTION0010600000000000000000): " This mangling is done without regard of the syntactic position of the identifier, so it can be used to define class-private instance and class variables, methods, as well as globals, and even to store instance variables private to this class on instances of *other* classes."

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica. I'm pretty sure it still is. Mangling in general is a feature, yes.  But some of the side effects are not.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: The existence of mangling is still advertised, but the tutorial no longer explicitly calls out the possibility of using it to create private globals or to create your-class-private variables on instances of other classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name mangling happens anywhere in a class body according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers):

> When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a private name of that class ...  This transformation is independent of the syntactical context in which the identifier is used.

The tutorial [example](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) shows that the mangling happens to attributes within the class too.

But the real problem is that your code is confusing namespaces. The constructor you showed originally

```
def __init__(self, x):
    __x = x
```

creates a **local** variable `_test__x`, which gets discarded as soon as it completes.

To properly assign an instance attribute:

```
def __init__(self, x):
    self.__x = x
```

This will create an attribute whose name is actually `_test__x`.

If you actually want to assign the global:

```
def __init__(self, x):
    global __x
    __x = x
```

Or

```
def __init__(self, x):
    global _test__x
    __x = x
```

The getter needs to access the instance attribute just as the constructor needs to set it. The current version is accessing the global because the name `_tesy__x` does not exist in the local namespace:

```
def rex(self):
    return __x
```

To return an attribute, add the namespace:

```
def rex(self):
    return self.__x
```

All that being said, if you had a module-level attribute with a leading double underscore (which you just shouldn't do), you would have a very hard time accessing it in the class. You would have to go through `globals`, something like this:

```
globals()['__x']
```

Shameless plug of my question about that from a long time ago: [How to access private variable of Python module from class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34621484/2988730).

Another fun fact: name mangling won't happen at all if your class name is all underscores. You can escape all your problems by naming classes `_`, `__`, `___`, `____`, etc.